# json encoded return data dependant on way login data provided?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What I'm getting is so strange I don't even know how to properly phrase the question.

Setup:
iOS App sends POST data (sql query) to php which then sends query to mysql database.  Result gets json encoded and sent back to iOS App.

When I first wrote the program, I just wrote the mysql database username, password, database-name inside the php script and everything worked fine:
(Option1)

```
self::$queryConnection = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'test_db');
```

I'm now building the login page in my iOS App so I switched it over to taking POST variables instead:(Option 2)

```
self::$queryConnection = new mysqli('localhost', $iOSDBUsername, $iOSDBPassword, $iOSDBName);
```

Now suddenly, my iOS App complains that:

> JSON Error retrieving Floor Data DBcom.getFloorData: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7fe7ee22d690 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})

To make sure the connection via POST variable login is fine, I hardcoded a query and assigned it to a test button.  That works fine using the login credentials passed via POST.  Essentially, with absolutely nothing else changed if I use Option 1, my program works fine.  If I use Option 2, I get the jsonError.

Below is the php script.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**php code:**

```
<?php

$iOSQuery = $_POST['iOSQuery'];
$iOSFlag = $_POST['iOSFlag'];
$iOSDBUsername = $_POST['iOSDBUsername'];
$iOSDBPassword = $_POST['iOSDBPassword'];
$iOSDBName = $_POST['iOSDBName'];

class Db 
  {
  protected static $queryConnection;

  public function sendQuery($theQuery, $theUser, $thePass, $theDB)
  {
    $queryResultsArray = array();
    //USING LINE BELOW GIVES JSON ERROR.
    self::$queryConnection = new mysqli('localhost', $theUser, $thePass, $theDB); 
    //USING LINE BELOW WORKS PERFECTLY. 
    //self::$queryConnection = new mysqli('localhost', ‘user', ‘pass', ‘dbname');
    if (self::$queryConnection->connect_error)
    {
      echo("Connection Problem");
    }
    else
    {
      $queryResults = self::$queryConnection->query($theQuery);
      if ($queryResults === false)
      {
        return false;
      }
      while ($queryResultRow = $queryResults->fetch_assoc())
      {
        $queryResultsArray[] = $queryResultRow;
      }
      self::$queryConnection->close();
      return $queryResultsArray;
    }
  }

  public function close()
  {
      self::$connection -> close();
  }
}

$db = new Db();
if ($iOSFlag == 99) //this 'if' block is linked to my test button
{
  $results = $db->sendQuery("show databases",$iOSDBUsername, $iOSDBPassword, $iOSDBName);
  echo json_encode($results);
}
else
{
  $results = $db->sendQuery($iOSQuery, $iOSDBUsername, $iOSDBPassword, $iOSDBName);
  $size = count($results);
  echo json_encode($results);
}
$db -> close();

?>
```

**Update:**

In my iOS App I wrote a `println` before the if let json decoding so I can see what the App is receiving from the php script.  When I use the hard coded line, I get normal json data as expected.  When I comment out the hard coded login and use my POST passed login, the json Data comes back as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

well it seems your are using wrong variables for user and password.. your are using $iOSUser and $iOSPass but you have actually declared it as $iOSDBUsername and $iOSDBPassword... so try replacing them in query as follows -

`new mysqli('localhost', $iOSDBUsername, $iOSDBPassword, $iOSDBname);`

Comment: Sorry, the "Option 2" code is just to illustrate.  If you actually look at the full code you will see that the passing is correct.  Comes in as $iOSUsername, get's passed as $iOSUsername in `$results = $db->sendquery($iOSQuery, $iOSUsername...`, gets taken in `sendQuery()` as `$theUser` and gets used inside `sendQuery()` as `$theUser`.  I will edit my post to remove the confusion.  Thanks.

Comment: no its not, check your code you are using $iOSUsername but you actually declared $iOSDBUsername even in your code its [$results = $db->sendquery($iOSQuery, $iOSDBUsername....] not what you said..

Comment: Arrrgghhhh.  I don't see it in the code.... Sorry there are no line numbers but:  5th line from the very top I have `$iOSDBUsername = $_POST['iOSDBUsername'];`.  7th line from the bottom I have `$results = $db->sendQuery($iOSQuery, $iOSDBUsername, $iOSDBPassword, $iOSDBName);`.  And then in the sendQuery() function I use `$theUser`.  I really do not see any discrepancy in my variable name.  I apologize that I cannot see what you are pointing out.